# Run script using Task Scheduler with user context complete silent with no popup or cmd flash

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I have tried to run the script using command

```
cmd.exe /c Start /min powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file <file>.ps1
```

But getting a CMD window for a fraction of a second. I need it to run completely hidden.

Comment: Just run the PowerShell script without all the `start` and `hidden` mumbo jumbo and enable the checkbox "run whether user is logged on or not" on the task.

Comment: The comment by @AnsgarWiechers should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue and the only way I could fix it was to call the PowerShell script with a simple VBS wrapper:

https://github.com/gbuktenica/PsRun

```
' SYNOPSIS
'   Run a PowerShell script in the user context without a script window
' EXAMPLE
'   wscript.exe PsRun.vbs MyPsScript.ps1
' AUTHOR
'   Glen Buktenica

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
For Each arg In args
    Dim PSRun
    PSRun = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy bypass -NonInteractive -File " & arg
    objShell.Run(PSRun),0
```

Comment: The bit of magic that makes the VBS run hidden is the 0 at the end of the line:
objShell.Run(PSRun),0

Comment: Glen Buktenica's script works fine, but the "For" needs a "Next".

Answer (score 2):

Configure the scheduled task to run whether the user is logged on or not:

[image]

and reduce the commandline to this:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

This makes the task run in the background with no visible window.

Comment: You may need to add yourself to Backup Operators group for this to work because running a task in the background under your account(If the script requires higher privilages) will require the Run Batch permission.  I solved the problem slightly differently from this article by adding myself to Backup Operators: https://danblee.com/log-on-as-batch-job-rights-for-task-scheduler/